# React Drag and drop TypeError: node.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drrag and drop feature to a react application using react-dnd. I'm getting the below error after bundling with webpack.

```
TypeError: node.addEventListener is not a function
```

I'm unsure what the error means and i do not understand the webpack debugger in the console
[image]

my code:

```
import React,{Component,PropTypes} from 'react';
import {DropTarget} from 'react-dnd';

const ShoppingCartSpec = {
  drop(){
    return {name:'ShoppingCart'}
  }
};

let collect = (connect,monitor) => {
  return {
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver:monitor.isOver(),
    canDrop:monitor.canDrop()
  };
}

class ShoppingCart extends Component{
  render(){
    const {canDrop,isOver,connectDropTarget} = this.props;
    const isActive = canDrop && isOver;

    let backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';

    if (isActive) {
      backgroundColor: '#F7F7BD';
    }else{
      backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7';
    }

    const style={
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor
    };
    return connectDropTarget(
      <div className="shopping-cart" style={style}>
        {isActive? 'Hmmmm,Snack' : 'Drag here to order'}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

as per the console, the problem appears to be with connectDropTarget. But i'm unsure where exactly the error is.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Believe the problem was due to an new version of React DND - I just cloned the package.json of pro -react and everything seemed to work fine :)